The DataLoader in PyTorch modifies my data
I am trying to train my deep network on the MNIST dataset. When I try to upload the dataset to the dataloader and get the batched data through the iterator, I get modified data that differs from the original (I attached two images). At the same time, my model learns well from them: the error drops, and the accuracy metric grows, which is why I conclude that everything should work like this. Maybe there is a function that the dataloader applies to my data, but I don't know about it?
You can view the notebook with the code and my problem here.
I have checked two versions of pytorch and two different datasets, but the problem persists everywhere.

Could you please share minimal reproducible example? Thx

@JohnnyCheesecutter I edited the question and added a link to the ipynb notebook.

The dataloader iterator produces a batch of images. Make sure you are plotting individual images and not the whole batch with plt.imshow().

@berinaniesh thanks for the help, but I'm only taking the first image from the batch, not the whole batch
